# как вызывать методы из другого класса с нижними регистрами?

Tags: flutter, dart

как вызывать методы из другого класса с нижними регистрами?

Например есть такой класс:

```
class Zip{
  List<ZipData> keys = [...];
  String encrypt({String stringForEncrypt}) {
    String string = stringForEncrypt;
    keys.asMap().forEach((index, value) {
      string = _zip(string: string, index: index);
    });
    return string;
  }


  String _zip({String string, int index}) {...}
}
```

я вызываю данный метод следующим образом:

```
String str = Zip().encrypt(stringForEncrypt: "lorem ipsum");
```

но я бы хотел вызывать данный метод внутри других классов как:

```
String str = zip.encrypt(stringForEncrypt:"lorem ipsum");
```

как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать `static` метод:

```
class Zip{
  static List<ZipData> keys = [...];
  static String encrypt({String stringForEncrypt}) {
    String string = stringForEncrypt;
    keys.asMap().forEach((index, value) {
      string = _zip(string: string, index: index);
    });
    return string;
  }


  String _zip({String string, int index}) {...}
}

...

Zip.encrypt(stringForEncrypt:"lorem ipsum");
```